# When recursively creating XML tree parent namespace gets lost

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

## The problem

I am currently creating a program to edit xml files which are being created by a financing software.

I need to add a subtree structure and add a specific value to it (this is not the issue).
What I struggle with is understanding how XElements work with namespaces.

The substructure should look like this:

```
<Id>
    <OrgId>
        <Othr>
            <Id>VALUE</Id>
        </Othr>
    </OrgId>
</Id>
```

And is supposed to be added on an existing childelement in the document which looks like this:

```
[...]
    <InitgPty>
        <Nm>SomeName</Nm>
        //add substructure here
    </InitgPty>
[...]
```

Below is my first solution with builds the tree recursivly while reading the namespace from the previous element (the InitgPty-Element, which inherits it namespace from the document if I understand it correctly).

### Recursively building the subtree (with reading the namespace from each root)

Find the target element:

```
var ns = xDoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace(); //xDoc is my XDocument which is read from file

var targetElement = xDoc.Descendants(
    ns + "InitgPty" ).First();
```

The function call:

```
BuildXmlSubTreeOnRoot(
    targetElement, // this is the <InitgPtyElement>
    new[]
    {
        "Id",
        "OrgId",
        "Othr"
    } );

//the function
public XElement BuildXmlSubTreeOnRoot( XElement root, string[] args, int startIndex = 0 )
{
    if (root == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else if( args.Length - startIndex > 0)
    {

        root.Add(
            BuildXmlSubTreeOnRoot(
                new XElement( root.GetDefaultNamespace() + args[startIndex]),
                args.SubArray( ++startIndex, args.Length - startIndex ))
            );
    }
    return root;
}

//Helper function subarray
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static T[] SubArray<T>( this T[] data, int index, int length )
    {
        T[] result = new T[length];
        Array.Copy( data, index, result, 0, length );
        return result;
    }
}
```

So what happens is the first root is `<InitgPty>` (with the document namespace inherited, debugger shows this),
then new XElement  is added as child while `root.GetDefaultNamespace` provides the namespace.
Then the recursive call on the new `<Id>` Child should add `<OrgId>` as a child to `<Id>` with the same namespace.

However `GetDefaultNamespace()` on `<Id>` as 'root' returns an empty XNamespace ('{}' in the debugger).
I **do not** understand this at all. I'd appreciate it if someone could help me out to understand this behaviour.

### Recursively building the subtree (with the namespace as parameter)

Now a workaround I found (but dislike) is passing the namespace to the recursive function directly:

```
public XElement BuildXmlSubTreeOnRoot( XNamespace nameSpace, XElement root, string[] args, int startIndex = 0 )
{
    if (root == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else if( args.Length - startIndex > 0)
    {
        root.Add(
            BuildXmlSubTreeOnRoot(
                nameSpace,
                new XElement( nameSpace + args[startIndex]),
                args.SubArray( ++startIndex, args.Length - startIndex ))
            );
    }
    return root;
}
```

And then pass in the namespace I retrieved from the XDocument earlier
`var ns = xDoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();`

To reduce it to a single question:
**Why does the latter work but the former not?**

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Shouldn't the namespace be defined as a xmlns attribute?

Comment: @AndrewK The second line of the xml file contains this `<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.003.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.003.03 pain.001.003.03.xsd">` So all other items inherit that namespace (if I understood namespaces correctly). If your refer to inserting the namespace in the constructor of the `XElement`s, I just found that as possible solutions when researching.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to that. In this case why should you even bother about setting the namespace for child elements if you have that set on the root element?